# The Pl/SQL Code doesn't give any output

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm a beginner in PL/SQL Coding.
This is a test program.

Can you please tell the reason for no output.

Please guide me.

```
create or replace package menu as
procedure show(name varchar2);

end menu;
/

create or replace package body menu as
procedure show(name varchar2) AS
new_number number;
begin
select count(*) into  new_number from stock;

dbms_output.put_line('This is output.');

end;
end menu;
/
```

Comment: select count(*) into  new_name from stock;  -- into new_number and set serveroutput on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set Oracle to output lines to the console manually:

```
set serveroutput on;
```

This should be the first line in your code.

Comment: thank you so much. :)

i'll look forward to post many more questions.. :D

Answer (score 1):

1. As others have said, SQL*Plus will only get the output from DBMS_OUTPUT if you first `SET SERVEROUT ON`.
2. Your code merely compiles and stores a database package on the database; you haven't actually *run* it. To run it you'd execute something like this:

   ```
   BEGIN menu.show('something'); END;
   /
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_output.htm#i1000634)

> ```
> Operational Notes
>
> If you do not call GET_LINE, or if you do not display the messages on your screen in SQL*Plus, the buffered messages are ignored.
>
> SQL*Plus calls GET_LINES after issuing a SQL statement or anonymous PL/SQL calls.
>
> Typing SET SERVEROUTPUT ON in SQL*Plus has the effect of invoking
>
> DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE (buffer_size => NULL);
> with no limit on the output.
>
> You should generally avoid having application code invoke either the DISABLE Procedure or ENABLE Procedure because this could subvert the attempt of an external tool like SQL*Plus to control whether or not to display output.
>
> Note:
> Messages sent using DBMS_OUTPUT are not actually sent until the sending subprogram or trigger completes. There is no mechanism to flush output during the execution of a procedure.
> Exceptions
>
> DBMS_OUTPUT subprograms raise the application error ORA-20000, and the output procedures can return the following errors:
>
> Table 68-1 DBMS_OUTPUT Errors
>
> Error Description
> ORU-10027:     Buffer overflow
> ORU-10028:     Line length overflow
>
> Rules and Limits
>
> The maximum line size is 32767 bytes.
>
> The default buffer size is 20000 bytes. The minimum size is 2000 bytes and the maximum is unlimited.
> ```

So SET SERVEROUTPUT ON is only for SQL*Plus.